# Constructor without parameter with two "New" Keywords

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm busy learning Repository pattern and while watching this youtube video [here](https://youtu.be/BJWQmq709kE?t=844) at 14:05

I realized that the guy put two **new** keywords in a **parameterless constructor** whereas I have never came across something like that before.

I know that the **new** keyword is used to create a new instance of a object like

```
Bird firstBird = new Bird();
```

but I have never seeen the below way of doing this.

```
private Iempployee iemp;

public EmpController()
{
    this.iemp = new RepositoryEmployee(new SampleDBEntities());
}
```

The only way I know how to do it in a *parameterless constructor* is :

```
 public EmpController()
 {
   this.iemp = "some string";
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with `EmpController` being parameterless. It's just initialing `iemp` to a new `RepositoryEmployee`, which is taking a `SampleDBEntities` as a parameter.

Comment: is there any way of doing it?

Comment: @TotalCode: Of doing *what*, exactly?

Comment: This code is reasonable but in my opinion the naming is terrible, and this is why you aren't understanding it. I suggest you to learn from another source.

Comment: I don't agree with downvoting or closing this question - the question is clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly equivalent to:

```
private Iempployee iemp;

public EmpController()
{
    SampleDBEntities entities = new SampleDBEntities();
    this.iemp = new RepositoryEmployee(entities);
}
```

They just saved a line by combining them.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing strange here. The constructor code is just like any other code. This code initializes `this.iemp` to something. This something happens to be a `RepositoryEmployee` object, whose constructor requires `SampleDBEntities` object.

To create an `EmpController` you would write `new EmpController()`, and as far as you are concerned this is the only `new` that you should care about.